# Cilium Cluster Mesh at Azure

Tags: azure, cilium

I need your help to create multi-cluster networking.

What i have done:

1- kubectl apply -f chaining.yaml

2-

```
`helm template cilium \
  --namespace cilium \
  --set nodeinit.azure=true \
  --set global.cni.chainingMode=generic-veth \
  --set global.cni.customConf=true \
  --set global.nodeinit.enabled=true \
  --set global.cni.configMap=cni-configuration \
  --set global.tunnel=disabled \
  --set global.etcd.enabled=true \
  --set global.etcd.managed=true \
  > cilium.yaml
kubectl create -f cilium.yaml`
```

3- kubectl -n kube-system edit cm cilium-config

4- 
`apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: cilium-etcd-external
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 2379
  selector:
    app: etcd
    etcd_cluster: cilium-etcd
    io.cilium/app: etcd-operator`

5-

git clone https://github.com/cilium/clustermesh-tools.git
cd clustermesh-tools

./extract-etcd-secrets.sh

./generate-secret-yaml.sh > clustermesh.yaml

6-

./generate-name-mapping.sh > ds.patch
kubectl -n kube-system patch ds cilium -p "$(cat ds.patch)"

7-

kubectl apply -f clustermesh.yaml

kubectl -n kube-system delete pod -l k8s-app=cilium

Result:

[image]

Clusters can not see each other. Dou you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

To test that clusters do not see each other, are you running "cilium node list" and only seeing nodes form one of the clusters?

Have you followed all steps on the clustermesh troubleshooting guide? https://docs.cilium.io/en/v1.6/gettingstarted/clustermesh/#troubleshooting

If that doesn't help, I would recommend hopping on Cilium Slack (https://cilium.io/slack), chatting with developers/community members, and potentially providing a sysdump (https://docs.cilium.io/en/v1.6/troubleshooting/#automatic-diagnosis).